# show reference frames

Tags: gazebo-1.9, gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everybody,
can someone tell me how to show in gazebo the reference frames attached to the models and the world reference frame? It would save me from the headaches I am having .
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5642/show-reference-frames/) by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately, not all the reference frames are viewable. In gazebo 2.2 and higher, if you select the `View Center of Mass / Inertia` from the View menu, then it will display pink boxes representing the size of a box of uniform density with equivalent mass properties, and green lines that represent the link frame. Also, you can `View Joints` to see axis frames for the joints. Please make a [feature request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/new) on bitbucket if you need additional functionality.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) on 2014-03-20**:
I will surely do, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Since Gazebo 6, we have link frame visuals, just choose `View -> Link Frames`:

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-02-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1